# .focus() on keydown() only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to select an `<a>` tag with arrow keys, and visit the link using enter key. My implementation is really close, but after some debugging i can't seem to understand what's going wrong. the relevant code is below:

```js
var resultId = 0;
  $("#search-input").keydown(function(e) {
    var resultIdSelection = "#result-" + resultId;
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == "38") {
      if (resultId > 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(resultIdSelection)
        resultId--;
        $(resultIdSelection + " .item-link").focus();
      }
    }
    if (key == "40") {
      if (resultId < 5) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(resultIdSelection)
        resultId++;
        $(resultIdSelection + " .item-link").focus();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search-input">
<ul>
  <li id="result-0"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-1"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-2"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-3"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-4"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-5"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
</ul>
```

So the expected behavior is that when I hit the down key, it shifts the focus down an element, and if the up key is hit then it shifts up. It also should not exceed the max amount of list items, which is 6.

What is happening however, is that on every arrow key press, it only does the focus once. I need to click into the input and then the down key again to go to the next item.

*I'm not 100% sure but I think* I need to somehow figure out how to "reset" the focus on every arrow key down. I also think it might have to do with how `e.preventDefault()` is being handled here, but I have that in my keyCode conditional.

Based on the code provided, how best can I get the `.focus()` event to fire multiple times?

Comment: What's wrong with tab / shift-tab?  Here's not the code for that `   `

Comment: @freedomn-m that's one thing, but the question is about up and down arrow keys...

Comment: The problem is that your keydown event is on `#search-input` and, when you press a key, you change the focus with `.focus()` so the cursor is no in `#search-input` so you don't get any more events.

Comment: Try changing `$("#search-input")` to `$("#search-input,.item-link")`  - but you won't be able to use `resultId++` as the user will be able to click a link further down - so you need to `$(this).closest("ul").attr("id")` to get the current id and process from there.

Comment: On what element do I bind the keydown event? I tried the list item

Comment: The element that gets the focus - ie the `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `keydown` listener only fires when focus is on your input element. So once a user presses the up or down arrow once, focus is moved away from the input element, and the listener won't fire anymore.

Adding the listener to your whole document (or to a container element, or to each anchor tag) will fix that problem. See below for a working solution.

**UPDATE:** Fixed the code to correctly apply the focus on up and down arrow presses and change the targeted ID at the correct time.

```js
var resultId = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var resultIdSelection;
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == "38") {
if (resultId > 0) {
  e.preventDefault();
  resultId--;
  resultIdSelection = "#result-" + resultId;
  console.log(resultIdSelection)
  $(resultIdSelection + " .item-link").focus();
}
  }
  if (key == "40") {
if (resultId < 5) {
  e.preventDefault();
  resultId++;
  resultIdSelection = "#result-" + resultId;
  console.log(resultIdSelection)
  $(resultIdSelection + " .item-link").focus();
}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search-input">
<ul>
  <li id="result-0"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-1"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-2"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-3"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-4"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
  <li id="result-5"><a class="item-link" href="#">Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Howcome when I hit down arrow, then up arrow right after, it doesn't go one item up?

Comment: @kawnah It's because of the order you are defining `resultIdSelection` and apply the `--` or `++` to your result ID. See my updated answer for a fix to that.

Comment: Got it. I just need to make one change: set `resultId` to `-1`. Before that it was skipping the first item.